# I get an error message for my temp table (Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [2:1])

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, temp-tables

I get the error message with this:

```
CREATE TABLE #percent_population_vaccinated
(
    continent NVARCHAR(255),
    location NVARCHAR(255),
    date datetime,
    population numeric,
    new_vaccinations numeric,
    rolling_vaccinations numeric
)

INSERT INTO #percent_population_vaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations
, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS rolling_vaccinations
FROM `my-project-0306-343712.portfolio_project_covid.covid_deaths` AS dea
JOIN `my-project-0306-343712.portfolio_project_covid.covid_vaccinations` AS vac
    ON dea.location = vac.location
    AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL 

SELECT *, (rolling_vaccinations/population) * 100
FROM #percent_population_vaccinated
```

I'm trying to follow along with the tutorial but I get stuck here.

Comment: What database are you using? the temp table syntax implies SqlServer but the use of back-quotes for table names in the FROM clause indicates something else. Temporary table syntax is quite different across RDBMS products, please tag the correct one

Comment: I'm using BigQuery. Should I use MySQL? I'm totally new to this so I'm trying out different things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: BigQuery uses `CREATE TEMP TABLE percent_population_vaccinated...` syntax to create temporary tables, as I understand. The `#` syntax is for SQL Server.
Tag your question with Google-BigQuery

Comment: First switch to using BigQuery syntax for creating temp tables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language (search, on page, for the keyword temporary); once you get the `CREATE TABLE` right, if you have further problems, come back here; update your question.